# how to write perl regular expression for a standard file name in C/C++

Tags: regex, perl, file-extension

I have files with following naming conventions:

- ***.c**  for a c source file. eg **abc_test.c**
- ***.cc** for a c++ source file. eg **abc_test.cc**
- ***.h** for a c header file.  eg **abc_test.h**
- ***.hh** for a c++ header file. eg **abc_test.hh**

How can i write a regular expression in perl to represent file names in these formats?

Answer (score 2):

Rather than use a regular expression, extract the extension and do your checks against it.

```
use File::Basename;
my(undef, undef, $ext) = fileparse($file, qr{\.(?:cc?|hh?)$});
print $ext;
```

Use `qr{\..+?}` to match any extension.

Comment: Isn't `qr{c, cc, h, hh}` supposed to be a regex, ala `qr{\.(?:cc?|hh?)$}`? Or am I missing something?

Comment: @Hugmeir Hmm, you were right. Fixed and also added a suggestion to match any extension.

Answer (score 0):

The simples I can imagine is `\.c$`, `\.cc$`, `\.h$` and `\.hh$`. A simple script could be:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
if ($ARGV[0] =~ /\.c$/) { print $ARGV[0] . "\n"; }
```

Use one of the online regex test offerings, e.g. http://www.regextester.com/

Comment: -- for PERL. http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq1.html#What%27s-the-difference-between-%22perl%22-and-%22Perl%22?

Comment: Never write "PERL", because perl is not an acronym, apocryphal folklore and post-facto expansions notwithstanding.

Comment: @Hugmeir, you can access the power of PERL in your Perl programs by using http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Inline::PERL

Comment: @daotoad: My goodness.. I've been so nearsighted! I can see forever now, thanks to PERL - The Practically Extinct Rubbish Language! http://www.defectiveperlprogramming.com/

Answer (score -1):

You can try [File::Basename](http://search.cpan.org/~jesse/perl-5.12.2/lib/File/Basename.pm) - Parse file paths into directory, filename and suffix,
like

```
    use File::Basename;
    my $from_file = 'abc_test.hh';
    (my $base,my $dir,my $ext) = fileparse($from_file,qr{\.(?:cc?|hh?)$});
    print $ext;
```

Comment: I don't think `qr{c, cc, h, hh}` will do what you think it will do, you might want `qw{c cc h hh}`.